# Auto replying with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using the following code to reply to a user that tweets "Hello World". It doesn't seem to be finding any users.

Can you see any issues with the code ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tweepy
#from our keys module (keys.py), import the keys dictionary
from keys import keys

CONSUMER_KEY = keys['consumer_key']
CONSUMER_SECRET = keys['consumer_secret']
ACCESS_TOKEN = keys['access_token']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = keys['access_token_secret']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

twts = api.search(q="Hello World!")     

#list of specific strings we want to check for in Tweets
t = ['Hello world!',
    'Hello World!',
    'Hello World!!!',
    'Hello world!!!',
    'Hello, world!',
    'Hello, World!']

for s in twts:
    for i in t:
        if i == s.text:
            sn = s.user.screen_name
            print s
            m = "@%s Hello!" % (sn)
            s = api.update_status(m, s.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the results from a web search

https://twitter.com/search?q=Hello%20World!

The results generally have hello and world, rather than the specific forms you want.  You can narrow this slightly in your API call by surrounding with quotes e.g.

But you will still find results like

"Hello World! Listen to this song! https://t.co/x8QUmIHrVk\nMy CMD NJ Family.......NSR & NSP"

Answer (score 0):

A general good practice would be to print the objects you're working with to see what they contain.

In your method above, you are checking that `i == s.text`.

This will only evaluate `True` when a tweet **only** contains an exact match from your list `t`.  So, if someone tweets "Hello World! What a wonderful world" your conditional will evaluate `False`.

```
for s in twts:
    print s.text # Let's see what's in s.text
    for i in t:
        if i == s.text:
            sn = s.user.screen_name
            print (sn,s.text)
```

Here are the first three `s.text` objects:

> RT @TheCamcorderApp: Hello World ;)
>
> @KaoruAIX No son pines! Vamos a hacer un juego en equipos para fomentar la unión de Hello, World y FAIX (?)
>
> infosbench #TILab #SmartCity #OpenAirLab -- hello world! 9887 person seated!

In summary, explore using the `in` operator for your specific method.  Instead of `i == s.text:`, use `i in s.text:`  There are also several questions on SO tagged [tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tweepy).  They'll give you other ideas on more efficient ways of parsing tweets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error
`TypeError: API.update_status() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

then all you have to do is mention the field names inside api.update_status() function, like this

`api.update_status(status=m, in_reply_to_status_id=s.id)`